# Lubuntu from USB

Tags: usb, lubuntu

I have An Acer Aspire 1362 Laptop with AMD Sompron 2800+ processor and only 256MB RAM, with Windows XP installed. I have downloaded Lubuntu-12.04-alternate-i386.iso and installed it to a 16GB USB stick. I do not want to install Lubuntu on my hard drive (yet!).

I have got the USB stick to boot, and am working my way through the menu. At one stage, the installer wants to partition my hard drive, so I abort the installation.

There doesn't seem to be an option on the menu to boot and run Lubuntu from the USB stick without putting stuff on the hard drive. How can I achieve this, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you installed in the USB is the *Lubuntu-installer*, and not the *Lubuntu-ready-to-use*

Goto [www.pendrivelinux.com] and follow the instructions to see how to install into an USB